# Key press event for validate the overs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to validate the text box such as overs per over only 6 balls I need to restrict the `1.7` or `11.7` the overs is start from `0.0` to `0.5` if user can enter `0.6` I need to change it as `1.0` please some one help me friends. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this,

```
$('#text').keyup(function(){
    if(isNaN(this.value))
        this.value=this.value.slice(0,-1);
    var num = this.value.split('.');
    if(num[1]>6)
        this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1);
    else if(num[1]==6)
        this.value=(parseInt(num[0],10)+1)+'.0';
});
```

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Pj6dB/4/)</kbd>

Comment: Friend its allowing the character also

Comment: for the long key press Alpha is allowed